# Bootstrap carousel text dim in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.1 and I notice that text dims when the carousel scrolls in Safari.
Chrome is fine.

Here's a demo, using sample code from the official site: http://s.codepen.io/resting/debug/QwEoPp?
Pen: http://codepen.io/resting/pen/QwEoPp

Code:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x400" alt="...">

      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x400" alt="...">

      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      Text dim in Safari when carousel scrolls.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone has any fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried addding `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` or `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the text? Text flickering in safari seems to be a common issue, and these are the two common fixes.

```
.carousel-inner {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried adding those 2 styles to the `body,html` selector but it didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: I think you need to apply them to the specific element that contains the text.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working with `carousel-inner` selector. Added my solution too.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed with

```
.carousel-inner {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```